.Net DI register generic and more specific generic
I have an interface IFlattener<T> and I want to create a class ListFlattener<T> : IFlattener<IList<T>> to iterate over obejcts and call their flattener on them.
I have a number of flatteners
ZoneFlattener : IFlattener<Zone>
ZoneGroupFlattener : IFlattener<ZoneGroup>
OperationFlattener : IFlattener<Operation>
All of which are registered
services.AddScoped<IFlattener<Zone>, ZoneFlattener>()
services.AddScoped<IFlattener<ZoneGroup>, ZoneGroupFlattener>()
services.AddScoped<IFlattener<Operation>, OperationFlattener>()

In a number of places I have a List<Zone> or List<ZoneGroup> and instead of doing the same loop over them all every time I want to have IFlattener<IList<T>> to do it for me.
public class ListFlattener<T>(IFlattener<T> flattener) : IFlattener<IList<T>> 
{
} 

How can I register this so constructors can take an IFlattener<IList<T>> and get a ListFlattener<T> that would in turn take an IFlattener
I've tried to register with the generics services.AddScoped(typeof(IFlattener<>), typeof(ListFlattener<>)) This does not work, it cannot resolve the dependency at runtime.
I know the alternative is to use an IListFlattener<T> and register that instead or perhaps use a different DI container which I would want to avoid.

What does This does not work. mean? You get a compilation or runtime error? You can't resolve the specific IFlattener<ConcreteType> you want in another service? What's the exact error?

BTW ListFlattener<T> doesn't implement IFlattener<T> and this particular registration is an infinite recursion - ListFlattener<T> requires an IFlattener<T> but the only registered service is a ListFlattener<T>. You could probably register services.AddScoped(typeof(IFlattener<IList<T>>), typeof(ListFlattener<>)) and services.AddScoped(typeof(IFlattener<T>), typeof(OtherFlattener<>)) separately. What are you trying to achieve with all this

ListFlattener<T> doesn't implement IFlattener<IList<T>> & IFlattener<T> .


I've tried to register with the generics services.AddScoped(typeof(IFlattener<>), typeof(ListFlattener<>)) This does not work

That is correct. MS.DI can't handle this more-advanced type of mapping. The generic type arguments of the abstraction must line up exactly with that of the implementation.
Instead, the only way to solve this is by making each closed-generic registration explicitly:
services.AddScoped<IFlattener<IList<Zone>>, ListFlattener<Zone>>();
services.AddScoped<IFlattener<IList<ZoneGroup>>, ListFlattener<ZoneGroup>>();
services.AddScoped<IFlattener<IList<Operation>>, ListFlattener<Operation>>();


If you try to resolve a IFlattener<IList<Zone>>, it requires a IFlattener<Zone>, which isn't registered and cannot be registered, because it has no implementation.

Ah, I've just noticed that the OP has edited their question and included a ZoneFlattener, so my comment is redundant.

Unfortunately, this is the right answer as DI only supports open generics without where criteria. Though you could enumerate the existing services to define each implementation automatically.
